# Sending Image via Telegram-Bot API with PHP

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I have this function

```
function suspendido($chat_id,$foo) 
{
  $TOKEN = "blablalbal";
  $TELEGRAM = "https://api.telegram.org:443/bot$TOKEN"; 
  $url.    = "https://zrabogados-pruebas.xyz/bot/404.png";
  $query = http_build_query(array(
    'chat_id'=> $chat_id,
    'photo'=> $url,
    'text'=> $foo,
    'parse_mode'=> "HTML", // Optional: Markdown | HTML
  ));
  $response = file_get_contents("$TELEGRAM/sendMessage?$query");
  return $response;

}
```

I try to sending an Image without using curl, tried to use file_get_contents but nothing works. Is something missing?.

Comment: I don’t see the description of `sendMessage` show any `photo` parameter – https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage Probably has to do with that it says _“Use this method to send text messages”_ there, I’d assume.

Comment: @CBroe my mistake. Yes, actually I have the $photo parameter. But the problem its more about that this code to nothing about photo'=> its like query ignore that.

Comment: I am not talking about whether _you_ have a $photo parameter, I am saying, the `sendMessage` endpoint _doesn’t take one_, because that is for sending _text_ messages.

Comment: @CBroe yes, but this is not the problem. The problem its why telegram servers are rejecting that. Acutally after a lot of research I found a Solution that will be publish here. I like to thank you for trying so hard to help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there is some problem with telegram servers.

If you put some image attributes into url it works.

```
function suspendido($chat_id,$foo) 
{
  $TOKEN = "blablalbla";
  $TELEGRAM = "https://api.telegram.org:443/bot$TOKEN"; 
  $url    = "https://zrabogados-pruebas.xyz/bot/404.png?center=140.50,36.15&width=1024&height=576";
  $query = http_build_query(array(
    'chat_id'=> $chat_id,
    'photo'=> $url,
    'text'=> $foo,
    'parse_mode'=> "HTML", // Optional: Markdown | HTML
  ));
  $response = file_get_contents("$TELEGRAM/sendMessage?$query");
  return $response;

}
```

I know its just silly but it works that way if you send the image url without this then you will receive a 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

You used `sendMessage` method, And this method isn't accept `photo` parameter.

And `$url` shouldn't be concatenated with another link.

To send photo use `sendPhoto` method like this:

```php
<?php
function suspendido($chat_id, $url, $foo) 
{
  $TOKEN = "<bot_token>";
  $TELEGRAM = "https://api.telegram.org:443/bot$TOKEN"; 
  $url = "https://zrabogados-pruebas.xyz/bot/404.png";
  $query = http_build_query(array(
    'chat_id'=> $chat_id,
    'photo'=> $url,
    'text'=> $foo,
    'parse_mode'=> 'HTML' // Optional: Markdown | HTML
  ));
  
  # Use sendPhoto here, Not sendMessage
  $response = file_get_contents("$TELEGRAM/sendPhoto?$query");
  return $response;
}
```

Comment: @JuanFernandoz , Check $chat_id you passed

Comment: Apparently, there is some problem with telegram servers check my response. thanks for your help Sr